# How to enable wifi using keyboard (Dell Inspiron 14r) in suse Linux 11.4

Tags: linux, opensuse, wifi

I have installed both Windows and SUSE Linux (11.4) on my Dell Inspiron 14r laptop. Both are working properly.

I am facing one strange problem.

I went to my Linux OS WiFi was working fine and I pressed <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> in-order to disable WiFi.
WiFi got disable successfully but when I again pressed <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> it is not enabling WiFi.
I can see WiFi disabled. Instead of that bluetooth icon got enable.

Then I switched to Windows and again pressed <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and WiFi got enabled.
Then I switched to Linux OS and I can see my WiFi enabled.
Again I pressed <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and it got disabled and I'm not able to enable it by pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> again.

How can I enable WiFi on SUSE (11.4)?

Comment: As a preliminary step, check your `journal` output and/or logs to see what happens when you press **Fn + F2**; I'm assuming your wifi connection isn't handled by `NetworkManager` or something similar, which would bind the interface automatically to your wifi-AP when it's brought back up.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me...
check this:

```
~# iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down
```

ok then  do this:

```
~# dhclient wlan0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

cancel it if it take too long.

and do it again:

```
~# iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 94:0C:6D:A7:96:3C
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-LINK_A7963C"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:9 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000007e1de6a181
                    Extra: Last beacon: 548ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E54502D4C494E4B5F413739363343
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C183048
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32041224606C
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: 00:26:44:85:C2:47
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ThomsonEDDA75"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000003a107ef188
                    Extra: Last beacon: 540ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000D54686F6D736F6E454444413735
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: DD7F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001017EE179186BD5CEA925EA803929929E11021000754484F4D534F4E1023000A54686F6D736F6E20544710240006353835207637104200093130323954465335351054000800060050F204000110110008544735383720563710080002000410570001001041000100
                    IE: Unknown: DD060010180200F0
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

now it's works!

re-do this:

```
dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: check your `rfkill` list of blocked devices: `$ rfkill list`

Answer (score 0):

Use yast2 for it `yast2 lan or yast lan` managing network devices with yast is much easier and better.

Answer (score -1):

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Replace `wlan0` with your wireless device. To see yours, you can type in `ifconfig -a`

Comment: i tried this but still not working. ifconfig -a result shows eth0,lo and wlan0 i executed ifconfig waln0 up but no effect. any idea?

Comment: in network manager icon on system tray enable wireless i unchecked and disabled.

Comment: if the `wlan0` interface is showing up already upon execution of `ifconfig`, then the above command won't have an effect on it--since it's already `up`!